# ensure_csrf_token is not setting the csrf cookie in cookies tab

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, csrf

I have this simple generic view:

```py
class GetCSRFToken(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]

    
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response('csrf is set')
```

and then, in react, i have this code:

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/csrf/').then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  },[])
```

so when react render the component that has the effect above, csrf token is not set in the application tab in cookie section

why is that??

Comment: `ensure_csrf_cookie` *checks* if the CSRF token has been submitted, it does not retrieves one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `get_token()` api, that django provide,

from `django.middleware.csrf` module

and make a simple view that return the token as a response.

On the frontend (React) side, you can either create an effect (`useEffect` hook), or mount a component in case you are using class component (`componentDidMount` method).

I will provide a functional component example:

```js
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';


function GetCsrfComponent(){
       const [token,setToken] = useState('')
       useEffect(()=>{
            axios.get("backend_endpoint/getcsrf/").then((res)=>{
                    setToken(res.data) // assuming the response is token itself
})  
 },[])
      return(
           <input hidden value={token} type='csrfmiddleware'/>
 )
}
```

A component has been created, you can deal with this component as a piece of UI that can be re-used in any other component

on the backend side, The following view:

```py
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets, views

class GetCsrfView(views.APIView):
      @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
      def get(self,request):
            return Response(get_token(),status=200)
 # note that i am using DRF (Django-Rest-Framework), which explains why i am returning a  `Response()` instance
```

And, as mentioned by @Willem Van Onsem, `ensure_csrf_token` is to ensure that csrf is being sent while sending the request from client side.

now, for urls.py:

```
from django_app_name import views

urlpatterns = [
path('getcsrf/',views.GetCsrfView.as_view(),name='csrf')
```

This should be a fully working example on how to obtain a csrf token from the backend and use it when sending post/create requests whenever needed.