# csrftoken is null in React-rendered form

Tags: reactjs, django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf

I am using purely React for the frontend, with Django on the backend.

I am using React to render a form & not using the Django form.

I am currently unable to make a POST request from my React front end (`http://localhost:3001/`) to my Django backend (`http://127.0.0.1:8000`) because of the `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /createListing` error.

This is what my POST request code looks like

```js
  async function getCSRFToken() {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCSRFToken");
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log("CSRFToken: ", jsonResponse["token"]);
    return jsonResponse["token"];
  }

async function createListing(listing) {
    let csrftoken = getCSRFToken();
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/createListing/",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(listing),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

This is my Django API endpoint

```py
def createListing(request):
    # Creating a new Listing must be via POST
    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)

    # Load Listing JSON from request body
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    # Retrieve Listing details
    name = data.get("name")
    description = data.get("description")
    rating = data.get("rating")
    price_nightly = data.get("price_nightly")

    # ... data manipulation

    return JsonResponse({"message": "Listing created successfully."}, status=201)
```

I have also created a Django view to retrieve a CSRF token from Django

`urls.py`

```py
path("getCSRFToken", views.getCSRFToken, name="getToken")
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def getCSRFToken(request):
    token = get_token(request)
    return JsonResponse({"token": token}, status=200)
```

I am following this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73862781/15781733).

Logging the CSRF Token to the console, I can see the CSRF Token is being generated but i'm still getting the same `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /createListing` error.

```js
// CSRF Token logged to console
KCr2laoLVmK9amwt0uBUKJze72T2qwLdbRbgPwOQdsKFGKIB2G5qA0940UsL2Bt0
```

I am able to generate the CSRF Token, but passing it into the headers in the POST request doesn't seem to work. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try again with this small modification in your Django's `view`.

```py
#first you need to import this
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt # add this decorator
def createListing(request):
    # Creating a new Listing must be via POST
    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)

    # Load Listing JSON from request body
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    # Retrieve Listing details
    name = data.get("name")
    description = data.get("description")
    rating = data.get("rating")
    price_nightly = data.get("price_nightly")

    # ... data manipulation

    return JsonResponse({"message": "Listing created successfully."}, status=201)
```

Comment: i am aware of the `@csrf_exempt` decorator but i don't want my Django view to be exempted from the CSRF protection, is there a way i can include the CSRF token in the header in the POST request?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, i am able to generate the CSRF Token from Django & include it in the headers in the POST request. But I am still getting the same `Forbidden (CSRF Cookie not set)` error.